# Cannot update a document

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

I am facing some problems trying to update a document. It is a simple update command but it didn't save any changes. So. I am looking for some advice.

This is the query:

```
db.Customers_DEV.update(
{"fn": "QA_Isabel10K"},
{
    $set: {
        "db" : ISODate("1988-08-17T06:00:00.000Z")
    }
});
```

The document does exist and it throws the next message as a result:

> Updated 0 record(s) in 50ms

Also tried by right clicking on the document and "Edit Document..." but here it throws the following error:

> Error when saving document: 1 Not primary while performing update on [database].

I am using Robomongo 0.9.0-RC10

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**

This is the document:

[Document to modify](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HTb1.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

**Solved.** Posting here for future reference.

I am not pretty sure how mongodb/robomongo works but the problem was the port number on my connection string. It unable me to make any insert nor update on the database.

Thanks and hope this help somebody else.

Answer (score 0):

for me, it helped to update Robo3T from 1.4 to 1.4.4